# How do I display calculated values in plain numbers rather than powers in Android.?

Tags: android

I have a Unit Converter. When I enter a value of 10000000 Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit, I get the answer 1.8000032E7. Its the correct answer but how do I make the app display 180000320 instead of 1.8000032E7 ??

Here's part of my Java code.

```
    celsiusET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        double in,out;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!machineChange) {
                machineChange = true;
                if(s.toString().equals("-")) {
                    kelvinET.setText("");
                    fahrenheitET.setText("");
                }
                else if(s.toString().equals(".")) {
                    kelvinET.setText("");
                    fahrenheitET.setText("");
                }
                else if(!s.toString().equals("")) {
                    in = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                    out = ((in*9)/5)+32;
                    fahrenheitET.setText(String.valueOf(out));
                    out = in+273.15;
                    kelvinET.setText(String.valueOf(out));
                }
                else {
                    kelvinET.setText("");
                    fahrenheitET.setText("");
                }
                machineChange = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private DecimalFormat formatter;

formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##,##,###");

act_income_basic_sal_etxt.setText(formatter.format((int)myApplication.getTaxCalculationModel().getA3()));

Specify your format in DecimalFormat and you will get your number as you want.

Answer (score 0):

[`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) can do that for you.

> DecimalFormat is a concrete subclass of NumberFormat that formats
>   decimal numbers. It has a variety of features designed to make it
>   possible to parse and format numbers in any locale, including support
>   for Western, Arabic, and Indic digits. It also supports different
>   kinds of numbers, including integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4), percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be localized.